# Structuring large app with cluster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, structure, worker

I recently tried to cluster my nodejs app without the use of PM2.
This, however, has proven to be slightly tedious since there is not "golden standard" of how to manage a larger codebase when using the cluster module.

For example, many tutorials give the following structure on how to implement the  cluster module *(example simplified)*:

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  // ALL code goes HERE?
  http.createServer().listen(8000);
}
```

If I wanted to define express routes or set up a socket.io server (this could be hundreds of lines), for example, I shouldn't possibly put all of that in the `else` statement (where `cluster.isWorker` is `true`), should I?